# Save EZAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ezaudio

So I use [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio#EZOutput) and OSX. I give to file some effects. And I don't to know how can i save it. How can i save EZAudioPlayer? Any ideas?

Comment: did you check  or read its documentation?

Comment: of course. I think, i can use EZAudioFloatConverter. But i don't understand how.

Comment: check with this method [EZRecorder recorderWithDestinationURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/file.caf"]
                                       andSourceFormat:audioFile.clientFormat];

Comment: At first i check it. But this method is for recorder. And i use EZAudioPlayer. So i open file in player, and i think that i need another method, or not?